# Libcurl - problem with using the function of write/read property

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux, libcurl

I'm developing an app for a embedded system, and inside the library that i have to use is [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/), the problem is that the embedded system that i am using does not use the write/read function of the ansi C, it requires the use of the property functions, doing so that the [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) doesn't function properly in the system.

I searched in the legal documentation and found the tags that could be configure by `curl_easy_setopt` :

- [CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION.html)
- [CURLOPT_READFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html)
- [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html)
- [CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION.html)

To my understanding, the cited tags, allow the configuration of the callback to be used after the execution of the respective functions, but not allowing me to alter the form of creating the `socket`, `write`, `read` and `close`.

So, how can I configure the [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) to execute property functions.

Comment: Response from the library developers: https://github.com/curl/curl/discussions/8712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is impossible without rebuilding libcurl.

libcurl relies on POSIX. You may rebuild libcurl to using your own socket API by defining the macros `sread(x,y,z)`, `swrite(x,y,z)`, `sclose(x)` and other POSIX socket function names prefixed by `s` in combination with functions [CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION.html), [CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION.html), [CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION.html).

See the examples in the sources:
[lib/curl_setup_once.h](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/curl_setup_once.h)
[lib/config-amigaos.h](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/config-amigaos.h)
...